# Problems whitelisting senders in Amavis-new

Tags: postfix, amavis, whitelist

I've a *CentOS6* server with *Amavis 2.9.1* + *Postfix 2.6.6* + clamav 0.99 that I use as **mail relay** (aka **mail gateway**), with network set as follow:
eth0 (**10.10.132.104**) as **external** inteface
eth1 (**10.10.133.104**) as **internal** interface (where it delivers mail to internal users, or outgoing mails come from)

I installed postfix with following master.cf (I paste only rilevant parts):

```
#smtp   inet    n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
10.10.133.104:smtp      inet    n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
  -o cleanup_service_name=no-headerchecks
  -o content_filter=
127.0.0.1:smtp  inet    n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
   -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
   -o cleanup_service_name=no-headerchecks
   -o content_filter=
10.10.132.104:smtp      inet    n       -       y       -       -       smtpd

127.0.0.1:10025 inet n    -       y       -       -     smtpd
   -o content_filter=
   -o smtpd_delay_reject=no
   -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
   -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
   -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
   -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
   -o smtpd_data_restrictions=reject_unauth_pipelining
   -o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions=
   -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
   -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8,10.0.0.0/8
   -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
   -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
   -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
   -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0
   -o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0
   -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_milters,no_address_mappings
   -o local_header_rewrite_clients=
   -o smtpd_milters=
   -o local_recipient_maps=
   -o relay_recipient_maps=
….
….
amavisfeed unix    -       -       n        -      2     lmtp
   -o lmtp_data_done_timeout=1200
   -o lmtp_send_xforward_command=yes
   -o disable_dns_lookups=yes
   -o max_use=20
```

In other hands, amavis at the moment only acts in mails incoming from external network.
In main.cf, amavisfeed is specified as filter default:

```
...
content_filter=amavisfeed:[127.0.0.1]:10024
...
```

My main purpose, in amavis, is to block all (in addition to viruses, bad headers, etc..) **banned files**, including *.zip* and *.rar*, **but** some senders exception.

So, in my amavis.conf, I changed  $banned_filename_re, adding a line so it reads:

```
  qr'^\.(zip|rar)$'i,                            # block zip and rar type
```

The block works fine, until I use some “bypass_” filter in order to avoid block when some mails are incoming from some senders.
Using the following policy bank (For instance, *my domain is “test.mydomain.com”*):

```
read_hash(\%whitelist_sender, '/etc/amavisd/whitelist');
@whitelist_sender_maps = (\%whitelist_sender);

$interface_policy{'10024'} = 'EXTERNAL';

# regular incoming mail, originating from anywhere (usually from outside)
$policy_bank{'EXTERNAL'} = {
  # # just use global settings, no special overrides
  log_level => 4,
  auth_required_release => 0,  # do not require secret_id for amavisd-release
   bypass_banned_checks_maps => [[qw( recip1@example.com user@libero.it user@test.mydomain.com )]],
};
```

Now suppose that **external user** “*user@libero.it*” sends a mail to my **internal user** “*user@test.mydomain.com*” with a .zip attachment. 
It passes successfully, but BECAUSE RECIPIENT IS MATCHED (and **not the SENDER**) .. :
From the log:

```
….
Mar 16 14:58:57 test-mailgw amavis[10230]: (10230-01) dkim: public key s=s2014 d=libero.it k=rsa, 2048-bit key
Mar 16 14:58:57 test-mailgw amavis[10230]: (10230-01) dkim: VALID Author+Sender+MailFrom signature by d=libero.it, From:
<user@libero.it>, a=rsa-sha256, c=relaxed/relaxed, s=s2014, i=@libero.it
Mar 16 14:58:57 test-mailgw amavis[10230]: (10230-01) Original mail size: 5472196; quota set to: 524288000 bytes (fmin=5,
fmax=500, qmin=102400, qmax=524288000)
Mar 16 14:58:57 test-mailgw amavis[10230]: (10230-01) Checking: xeO-t6yJ68dS EXTERNAL [212.48.25.196] <user@libero.it>-> <user@test.mydomain.com>
Mar 16 14:58:57 test-mailgw amavis[10230]: (10230-01) 2822.From: <user@libero.it>
Mar 16 14:58:57 test-mailgw amavis[10230]: (10230-01) lookup_acl(user@test.mydomain.com) matches key ".test.mydomain.com", result=1
Mar 16 14:58:57 test-mailgw amavis[10230]: (10230-01) lookup [local_domains] => true,  "user@test.mydomain.com" matches, result="1", matching_key=".test.mydomain.com"
Mar 16 14:58:57 test-mailgw amavis[10230]: (10230-01) lookup [bypass_virus_checks] => undef, "user@test.mydomain.com" does not match
Mar 16 14:58:57 test-mailgw amavis[10230]: (10230-01) lookup_acl(user@test.mydomain.com) matches key "user@test.mydomain.com", result=1
Mar 16 14:58:57 test-mailgw amavis[10230]: (10230-01) lookup => true,  "user@test.mydomain.com" matches, result="1", matching_key="user@test.mydomain.com"
Mar 16 14:58:57 test-mailgw amavis[10230]: (10230-01) lookup [bypass_spam_checks] => undef, "user@test.mydomain.com" does not match
Mar 16 14:58:57 test-mailgw amavis[10230]: (10230-01) Extracting mime components from a file
```

Infact, if I change the bypass_banned_checks_maps line, so to read:

```
   bypass_banned_checks_maps => [[qw( recip1@example.com user@libero.it )]],
```

and I resend the same mail, the sender **is not whitelisted**, and the mail is **blocked** (BANNED and BOUNCED) and quarantined:

```
…...
Mar 16 15:14:57 test-mailgw amavis[10611]: (10611-01) Checking: lCsEqup1nnwy EXTERNAL [212.48.25.196] <user@libero.it> 
-> <user@test.mydomain.com>
Mar 16 15:14:57 test-mailgw amavis[10611]: (10611-01) 2822.From: <user@libero.it>
Mar 16 15:14:57 test-mailgw amavis[10611]: (10611-01) lookup_acl(user@test.mydomain.com) matches key ".test.mydomain.com", result=1
Mar 16 15:14:57 test-mailgw amavis[10611]: (10611-01) lookup [local_domains] => true, "user@test.mydomain.com" matches, result="1", matching_key=".test.mydomain.com"
Mar 16 15:14:57 test-mailgw amavis[10611]: (10611-01) lookup [bypass_virus_checks] => undef, "user@test.mydomain.com" does not match
Mar 16 15:14:57 test-mailgw amavis[10611]: (10611-01) lookup_acl(user@test.mydomain.com), no match
Mar 16 15:14:57 test-mailgw amavis[10611]: (10611-01) lookup => undef, "user@test.mydomain.com" does not match
Mar 16 15:14:57 test-mailgw amavis[10611]: (10611-01) lookup [bypass_spam_checks] => undef, "user@test.mydomain.com" does not match
…...
Mar 16 15:14:58 test-mailgw postfix/lmtp[10620]: 64B778287E: to=<user@test.mydomain.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=2.1, delays=0.63/0.01/0.01/1.4, dsn=2.5.0, status=sent (250 2.5.0 Ok <user@test.mydomain.com>, DSN was sent (554 5.7.0 Bounce, id=10611-01 - BANNED: .pdf,joomla_15_quickstart.pdf))
Mar 16 15:14:58 test-mailgw postfix/qmgr[631]: 64B778287E: removed
…….
```

Becuase, substantially, it keeps on checking the recipient’s mail address, instead of the sender one ….

And now, one more weirder and weirder behaviour! If I change my EXTERNAL policy_bank, using read_hash from a whitelist include file, where I write an address per line, so to have:

- my **/etc/amavisd/whitelist** file that reads as follow:

  user1@externaldomain1.tld
  externaldomain2.tld
- and my **amavisd.conf**’s **policy bank** as follow:

  …...
  read_hash(\%whitelist_sender, '/etc/amavisd/whitelist');
  @whitelist_sender_maps = (\%whitelist_sender);

  $interface_policy{'10024'} = 'EXTERNAL';

  $policy_bank{'EXTERNAL'} = {
   log_level => 5,
   auth_required_release => 0,  # do not require secret_id for amavisd-release
    bypass_banned_checks_maps => ['@whitelist_sender_maps'],
  };
  ….

And I send the same mail of previous example (external “*user@libero.it*” to my internal “*user@test.mydomain.com*” ), I get:

```
…...
Mar 16 15:36:32 test-mailgw amavis[11088]: (11088-01) Checking: S6fD-MRTCySL EXTERNAL [212.48.25.196] <user@libero.it> -> <user@test.mydomain.com>
Mar 16 15:36:32 test-mailgw amavis[11088]: (11088-01) 2822.From: <user@libero.it>
Mar 16 15:36:32 test-mailgw amavis[11088]: (11088-01) lookup_acl(user@test.mydomain.com) matches key ".test.mydomain.com", result=1
Mar 16 15:36:32 test-mailgw amavis[11088]: (11088-01) lookup [local_domains] => true,  "user@test.mydomain.com" matches, result="1",matching_key=".test.mydomain.com"
Mar 16 15:36:32 test-mailgw amavis[11088]: (11088-01) lookup [bypass_virus_checks] => undef, "user@test.mydomain.com" does not match
Mar 16 15:36:32 test-mailgw amavis[11088]: (11088-01) lookup: (scalar) matches, result="@whitelist_sender_maps"
Mar 16 15:36:32 test-mailgw amavis[11088]: (11088-01) lookup => true, "user@test.mydomain.com" matches, result="@whitelist_sender_maps", matching_key="(constant:@whitelist_sender_maps)"
Mar 16 15:36:32 test-mailgw amavis[11088]: (11088-01) lookup [bypass_spam_checks] => undef, "user@test.mydomain.com" does not match
…..
```

… the mail passes as **Clean**, and arrives to its destination.  (In addition, why “result=”@whitelist_sender_maps” ?)

Could anybody help me, and suggest me where and why I’m mistaking???

Thanks in advance for any help.
Gabo

Comment: I don't have any answer for you, but while trying the same setup I noticed that with the changes to your EXTERNAL policy bank, banned checks are disabled for _all_ senders, not just those in the /etc/amavisd/whitelist file.

Answer (score 3):

It seems it is not possible to do this in amavis alone. An alternative would be to use a separate policy bank where checking for banned file names is disabled, and let Postfix direct emails from whitelisted sender addresses to that policy bank.

A basic implementation could be done as follows:

Add the following to amavisd.conf:

```
$interface_policy{'10026'} = 'NOBANNED';

$policy_bank{'NOBANNED'} = {
  # # just use global settings, no special overrides
  log_level => 4,
  auth_required_release => 0,
  bypass_banned_checks_maps => [1],
};
```

Create a file `/etc/postfix/whitelist_filter`, with contents like:

```
whitelisted@sender.com  FILTER smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10026
```

Create the hash file for this file:

```
postmap hash:/etc/postfix/whitelist_filter
```

And add the line

```
check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/whitelist_filter
```

somewhere in the `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`.